# Pullback of indecomposable bundles on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, vector-bundles

I consider an elliptic curve $\mathcal C$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and the multiplication by $[n]$ map on the curve. 
Then I consider an indecomposable vector bundle $E$ on $C$.
What can I say of the pullback $[n]^{*}E$? It is still indecomposable? If I know $E$ from the Atiyah's classification, may I say something more on $[n]^{*}E$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, that was a silly mistake. I will remove my comment

Comment: No problem! I will remove these comments too. Thanks for your interest anyway!